# Symfony sqlite migrations register adding a unique constraint

Tags: php, symfony

I've added the following unique constraint to my entity in symfony.

```php
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=FormTypeRepository::class)
 * @UniqueEntity("type")
 * @UniqueEntity("name")
```

However, running `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff` produces no differences.

Can this be done on the database level? SQLite supports the unique constraint.

If not, would this be enforced at a validation level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unique entity constraint will not create database "constraint" (unique index) for you, for this you have to add [Doctrine UniqueConstraint annotation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref_uniqueconstraint)